# RewriteRule - mod-rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following tricks in my .htaccess file, every thing is working fine on my local server or production server but when i upload this file to remote server it gives me an error of **500 Internal server error**, following lines are giving me an error

.htaccess is working fine on my production server but not on remote server

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Redirect /othersite.html http://www.othersite.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [nc]
RewriteRule ^Old_One$ nomoreoldies.php [L]
```

Comment: The first rule is rewriting all .htm files to .php and the 2nd Old_One to nomoreoldies.php, which doesn't match your description.  Which is it you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful while deploying your local files to remote server. Edit your file using ftp and check for invalid characters which are actually hidden. or recreate the file, remove invalid characters

Answer (score 2):

Please check that mod_rewrite is enabled at that server and that you can use rewrite rules via .htaccess in your directory.

*Edit (summing up comments):*

Additional tipps: check the log file for errors. In case of *Invalid command* both check for spelling and wrong file encoding which might replace spaces by some other chars so that mod_rewrite does not recognize the parts of the line.

If in doubt, recreate the whole file directly on the server using `vi` (or similar editor), without copy&paste to ensure proper file encoding on the server.

Comment: yes mod_rewrite is one but dont know how to check that can i use rewrite rules via .htaccess

Comment: I thought of checking the httpd/vhost configuration for `AllowOverride` (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) but I see that this might have little effect on the usage of mod_rewrite. Anyway, do you have access to the server error log?

Comment: This is the server error log

/home/nabuns/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 

'RewriteRule\xa0^(.*)\\.htm$\xa0$1.php\xa0[nc]', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Is there really an \xa0 in the file? Maybe the `.htaccess` file is in the wrong encoding (this would explain why Apache doesn't understand the command because it looks like a continous line without spaces between the parts). Can you recreate it using `vi` directly or otherwise convert/check the file encoding?

Comment: The xa0 will actually not be visible in the file when you use `vi` or any other editor to edit the file on the server. Please use a shell directly on the server (e.g. via SSH) and recreate the complete `.htaccess` by typing it in manually (no copy&paste!) from scratch, because that's the only way to make sure you'll get the encoding right.

Comment: Great that I could help. I've edited my answer to sum up my comments, so maybe you'd like to mark my answer as solution ;)

Comment: :) ... i have asked another question .. will you please solve it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366229/case-sensitive-urls-in-apache